# Adding buffer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, buffer, tools

i'm newbie in GIS.
i'm trying to make webgis using leaflet.
i already make layer with icon in leaflet.

```
/*layer*/
    var layer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("GIS/layer/request_layer.php", {
        middleware:function(data){ 
        return L.geoJson(data, {
            onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
                layer.bindPopup("<center>" + feature.properties.id + "<center>"),
                layer.setIcon(icon);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
        }
    });

/*icon layer*/
    var icon = L.icon({
            iconUrl : 'GIS/leaflet/images/icon.png',
            iconSize : [15,15],
            popupAnchor : [0, -28]
        });
```

how to add buffer in this layer ?

Answer (score 2):

Another easy option is Turf JS. It's easy to use with Leaflet. http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Buffer](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.buffer) plugin for leaflet.  If you are new to GIS and Leaflet then I recomend you spend some time reviewing all the [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) that are available to you as there are a lot and you'll find many of the invaluable for your purposes.