# Drawing buffer zones in React-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, buffer, leaflet-draw, react, leaflet-plugins

I am working with a Leaflet in react.js and using react-leaflet-draw. I can't draw a buffer on shapes drawn by react-leaflet-draw. Just like a “leaflet-buffer”. [image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242755/adding-buffer-in-leaflet see here maybe it will help you